# How to assign default values to a Django path

Tags: python, django

I am building a Django API where one of my paths in `urls.py` is:
`path('device_id/<str:device_id>/readings/<int:num_readings>, views.results, name='results')`

I want to avoid getting a 404 if a user specifies a device id but does not enter a number of readings. I'd like the assign a default value of readings to 10.

This url is connect to a view called **results**

`def results(request, device_id, readings):`

For example, if a user goes to:
`device_id/2132/readings/`
I would like device_id = 2132 and readings=10 in the **results** view

`device_id/2132/readings/24`
I would like device_id = 2132 and readings=24 in the **results** view

Comment: Define two paths pointing to the same view. In the view you'll have to check if `num_readings` is set.

Answer (score 4):

Add another path where you add defaults to the `kwargs`, like:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path(
        'device_id/<str:device_id>/readings/<int:num_readings>',
        views.results,
        name='results'
    ),
    path(
        'device_id/<str:device_id>/readings/',
        views.results,
        name='results10'
        kwargs={'num_readings': 10}
    ),
    # ...
]
```

So here the second view is a path without a `num_readings` variable, but the `kwargs` is a dctionary that contains additional (named) parameters to pass to the view.

Comment: I wanted to avoid doing that because I actually have 2 more optional values - I just included 2 here for simplicity. The number of paths /combinations would get quite large. Is there another solution or will I have to handle every case 'manually'

Comment: @PlanczerTank: not that I am aware of, since these are, strictly speaking, different URL patterns.

Answer (score 2):

What about specifying a default for readings in your view:

```
def results(request, device_id="", readings=10):
    # ...
```

and write urls like (use `re_path` in order to use regular expression to state that `num_readings` is optional):

```
urlpatterns = [
    re_path(
        'device_id/(?P<device_id>\w+)/readings/(?P<num_readings>\d+)?',
        views.results,
        name='results'
    ),
   # ...
]
```